# Swift: Testing with NSNotificationCenter

Tags: ios, unit-testing, swift

I'm trying to test my app by sending messages through NSNotificationCenter as the Application interface would do.

**Problem is posting from the TestCase class.** The same code works for posting within the App but causes the app to crash if posting from the unit test.

For testing this situation i made a simple SingleWindow application. 
Added this Message class for passing the message through userInfo parameter of postNotification:

```
class Message {
    var text:String = "Hi"
}
```

Added the messageHandler on the ViewControler, like this

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"messageHandler:", name:"WhatEverMessage", object:nil)

        //Send message to be catched on MessageHandler func.
        var userInfo = ["Message": Message()];
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("WhatEverMessage",object:self, userInfo:userInfo);
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func messageHandler(notification:NSNotification){

        let message = notification.userInfo!["Message"] as Message
        println((message as Message).text)

    }
}
```

When the App runs, viewDidLoad method send a message for itself, successfully unwrapped at the messageHandler

When i try to test the behaviour, by sending another message from the TestCase, the app crash. The code to post is exactly the same:

```
func testExample() {
    var userInfo = ["Message": Message()];
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("WhatEverMessage",object:self, userInfo:userInfo);
}
```

When i run the test i get an EXC_BREAKPOINT exception on posting the message, but no breakpoint is set for the project and then i get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS unwrapping the message on the messageHandler.

I think the problem is when posting from the testcase but don't have a clue. All compile and link settings are the default in this test project.

Already try many things, like derive Message from NSObject and others things with less sense. Stuck here.

Comment: It doesn't look like you're removing the observer on deinit. If a previous test has already created and destroyed an instance of your view controller, the dealloc'd view controller will still be observing the notification. Any chance that's what is happening?

Comment: No, it have only one test. 
Printing the received message i notice the namespace is wrong. It prints "Optional(`TargetAppTest`.Message)" and should be  `TargetApp.Message`. Anyway to instance an TargetApp.Message from the test code?

Comment: Where are you defining the Message class? Or, how are you sharing the Message class between your app target and its test target?

Comment: I ask because it looks like Message is a protected class, so you shouldn't be able to use it in both your app and your target without getting a compiler error. Did you add Message to your test target's Compile build phase? If so, that could be causing the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was the way that the Message class was used. The `Message` class was set as part of Test Target. This way, when target compiles it creates a new `Message` class. Because of that when the `messageHandler` try to cast the object into `Message` class it fails because the object has the `Message` class of target.

To use an `Message` object on test function, the `Message` class should be removed from target membership and imported instead.

Here the code changes:

```
public class Message {
    public init(){  //Initializer must be declared to make it public
    }
    public var text:String = "Hi"
}
```

At the test side:

```
import XCTest
import MyApp

class MyAppTests: XCTestCase {

   ...

    func testExample() {
        var userInfo = ["Message": MyApp.Message()]; //Specify namespace MyApp
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("WhatEverMessage",object:self, userInfo:userInfo);
    }
}
```